# Why is Jeremiah 31:9 translated as a third person plural?

Tags: hebrew, grammar, jeremiah

In the אֽוֹלִיכֵם֙ of Jeremiah 31:9, translated as "I will make them walk by brooks of water" (ESV), the pronominal suffix after "make them walk" sure looks like a second person masculine plural, not a third person MP. Should it not be translated as "I will make YOU walk?" It is kaf tsere mem, not he tsere mem.

Answer (score 2):

The *kaf* is the third radical (i.e., part of the root), not part of the suffix.

The word of interest is `אֽוֹלִיכֵם`. This is a [*hifil* imperfect first common singular](http://animatedhebrew.com/charts/paradigms/full_verb_paradigms.pdf)* from [הלך](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/236/mode/1up) with a third masculine plural suffix, *tsere-mem*. (The *he* is [not generally part of the 3mp suffix on imperfect forms.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gesenius%27_Hebrew_Grammar/58._The_Pronominal_Suffixes_of_the_Verb#GHGpar-58-ff)) The un-suffixed form ends in a *kaf*: `אוֹלִיךְ`.

`I will make them walk` is a good translation.

<sub>*Inflected, characteristically, as if I-*yod*, i.e. I-*waw* -- see linked paradigms.</sub>